# Android Ionic Cordova - Error: Failed to get absolute path to installed module

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I have created a custom plugin and I'm trying add it by cmd getting below error

```
> cordova plugin add C:\r\work\custom_plugins\cordova-plugin-webrtc-video-call -
-save
x Running command - failed!

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova plugin add
        C:\r\work\custom_plugins\cordova-plugin-webrtc-video-call --s... (exit
        code 1):

        Error: Failed to get absolute path to installed module


C:\r\work>
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<plugin id="cordova-plugin-webrtc-video-call" version="1.0.1" xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <name>WebrtcVideoCall</name>
    <js-module name="WebrtcVideoCall" src="www/WebrtcVideoCall.js">
        <clobbers target="cordova.plugins.WebrtcVideoCall" />
    </js-module>
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file parent="/*" target="res/xml/config.xml">
            <feature name="WebrtcVideoCall">
                <param name="android-package" value="com.hsc.plugin.webrtc.WebrtcVideoCall" />
            </feature>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="/manifest/application" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <activity
                android:name="com.hsc.plugin.webrtc.CallActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="fullUser"
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
                android:exported="true"
                android:theme="@style/CallActivityTheme">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.hsc.plugin.ACTION_CALL" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

        </config-file>
        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" required="false" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" required="false" />
            <uses-feature
                android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
                android:required="false"
            />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
        </config-file>
        <framework src="src/android/Webrtc.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference"/>

        <source-file src="src/android/AppRTCAudioManager.java" target-dir="src/com/hsc/plugin/webrtc" />
        <source-file src="src/android/AppRTCClient.java" target-dir="src/com/hsc/plugin/webrtc" />
        <source-file src="src/android/AppRTCProximitySensor.java" target-dir="src/com/hsc/plugin/webrtc" />
        <source-file src="src/android/CallActivity.java" target-dir="src/com/hsc/plugin/webrtc" />
        <source-file src="src/android/CallFragment.java" target-dir="src/com/hsc/plugin/webrtc" />
        <source-file src="src/android/CaptureQualityController.java" target-dir="src/com/hsc/plugin/webrtc" />
        <source-file src="src/android/CpuMonitor.java" target-dir="src/com/hsc/plugin/webrtc" />
        <source-file src="src/android/DirectRTCClient.java" target-dir="src/com/hsc/plugin/webrtc" />
        <source-file src="src/android/HudFragment.java" target-dir="src/com/hsc/plugin/webrtc" />
        <source-file src="src/android/PeerConnectionClient.java" target-dir="src/com/hsc/plugin/webrtc" />
        <source-file src="src/android/PercentFrameLayout.java" target-dir="src/com/hsc/plugin/webrtc" />
        <source-file src="src/android/RoomParametersFetcher.java" target-dir="src/com/hsc/plugin/webrtc" />
        <source-file src="src/android/TCPChannelClient.java" target-dir="src/com/hsc/plugin/webrtc" />
        <source-file src="src/android/UnhandledExceptionHandler.java" target-dir="src/com/hsc/plugin/webrtc" />
        <source-file src="src/android/WebrtcVideoCall.java" target-dir="src/com/hsc/plugin/webrtc" />
        <source-file src="src/android/WebSocketChannelClient.java" target-dir="src/com/hsc/plugin/webrtc" />
        <source-file src="src/android/WebSocketRTCClient.java" target-dir="src/com/hsc/plugin/webrtc" />
        <source-file src="src/android/util/AppRTCUtils.java" target-dir="src/com/hsc/plugin/webrtc/util" />
        <source-file src="src/android/util/AsyncHttpURLConnection.java" target-dir="src/com/hsc/plugin/webrtc/util" />

        <source-file src="src/android/libs/autobanh.jar" target-dir="libs" framework="true" />
        <source-file src="src/android/libs/libjingle-peerconnection-sources.jar" target-dir="libs" framework="true" />
        <source-file src="src/android/libs/libjingle-peerconnection.jar" target-dir="libs" framework="true" />
        <source-file src="src/android/libs/armeabi-v7a/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi-v7a" 
                     framework="true" />

        <!--  drawable src/android/resources -->
        <resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-hdpi/disconnect.png" target="res/drawable-hdpi/disconnect.png" />
        <resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-mdpi/disconnect.png" target="res/drawable-mdpi/disconnect.png" />
        <resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/disconnect.png" target="res/drawable-xhdpi/disconnect.png" />
        <resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-ldpi/disconnect.png" target="res/drawable-ldpi/disconnect.png" />
        <resource-file src="src/android/res/layout/activity_call.xml" target="res/layout/activity_call.xml" />
        <resource-file src="src/android/res/layout/fragment_call.xml" target="res/layout/fragment_call.xml" />
        <resource-file src="src/android/res/layout/fragment_hud.xml" target="res/layout/fragment_hud.xml" />
        <resource-file src="src/android/res/values/WebrtcPluginStrings.xml" target="res/values/WebrtcPluginStrings.xml" />
        <resource-file src="src/android/res/values/WebrtcPluginStyles.xml" target="res/values/WebrtcPluginStyles.xml" />

        <resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_full_screen.png" target="res/drawable-hdpi/iic_action_full_screen.png" />
        <resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_full_screen.png" target="res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_full_screen.png" />
        <resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_full_screen.png" target="res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_full_screen.png" />
        <resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-ldpi/ic_action_full_screen.png" target="res/drawable-ldpi/ic_action_full_screen.png" />

        <resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_return_from_full_screen.png" target="res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_return_from_full_screen.png" />
        <resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_return_from_full_screen.png" target="res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_return_from_full_screen.png" />
        <resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_return_from_full_screen.png" target="res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_return_from_full_screen.png" />
        <resource-file src="src/android/res/drawable-ldpi/ic_action_return_from_full_screen.png" target="res/drawable-ldpi/ic_action_return_from_full_screen.png" />



    </platform>
</plugin>
```

I have already tried with --nofetch option, I'm using cordova v7.0.1

Answer (score 6):

Make sure there is no file/symlink of the plugin into node_modules you want to install. If it's present, remove them and re-run the command:

`cordova plugin add C:\r\work\custom_plugins\cordova-plugin-webrtc-video-call --nofetch`

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several posts on this issue on SO.

It seems cordova is lost between the local path you're using to install your plugin and the information in config.xml regarding that plugin.

Some people seem to fix it by first removing the plugin with the --force flag and then re-install it:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-webrtc-video-call --force
cordova plugin add C:\r\work\custom_plugins\cordova-plugin-webrtc-video-call
```

(-save seems to be useless in cordova 7 since plugins are added to config.xml without that)

When I had the issue I fixed it by cleaning all plugins from the project and re-adding plugins :

1. delete the plugin folder
2. delete the platforms/android folder
3. remove all the plugin references in config.xml
4. re-add all the plugins to the project

ps: the xml file in your plugin is named plugin.xml and not config.xml, right?

Comment: Why should I delete platform  and my others plugin, Because it will take large to re-create platform ( ~ 20 mins) . I have tried with your one command remove with --force option, but it still not working Thank You

Comment: I don't say you should do it, just that it's what I did ;) My problem was when re-installing my own plugins and I have scripts to re-add all plugins and recreate the plathorm in no time. Maybe the issue is with the files plugin.xml or package.json?

Answer (score 0):

`--nofetch` option is the way to solve the issue as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46010348/327862

However, since Cordova 8.0.0, the `--nofetch` option has been removed: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13055

If you already have installed Cordova 8.x.x and would like to use the `--nofetch` option, then you need to downgrade cordova to 7.1.0.

Run the following command to downgrade Cordova to 7.1.0:

```
npm install -g cordova@7.1.0
```

If the above command doesn't work, then try uninstalling cordova at first and then install cordova version 7.1.0:

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova@7.1.0
```

Then, check the Cordova version to confirm if it's downgraded or not:

```
cordova --version
```